# How to run services even if app is closed (exited) from background with titanium alloy

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

How to run App even App is totally closed from my mobile background?

Concept of my App is to notify user with alert message or sound through Application when device battery is fully charged.

Currently its working when I working in App or paused with background mode But it should work even app is totally closed(exited) from background mode. It should get notification alert and sound through app even app is totally closed(exited)

Comment: only way is to use your service as an alarm

Comment: Hi vivek, How can i set my App as alarm ?

Comment: i don't know how to code in titanium

Answer (score 0):

With this module you can use the android AlarmManager: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager

Comment: The various options for background services iOS are documented here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Background_Services